# enum type needed on multiple class header files

Tags: c++, class, enums, header, enumeration

I am trying to make a C++ program that uses multiple classes (and multiple header files). I have made an enum type called 'move' in one of the classes but I need to access this type from all of the classes. If I leave the enum declaration in just one header file, the other classes can't access it, the compiler gives an error everywhere its used except in that class and main. If I declare it in main, no class can access it. If I declare it in every class header file, I get a compiler error for redefining it.

Where do I declare an enum type so that every class header file has access to it?

Comment: There is absolutely no rule that says that in C++ each header has one class (or each class has one header). In a small sized program (e.g. less than a dozen thousands lines) I recommend having only one common header file for the entire program!

Comment: In a header with other common declarations. If it must be declared in a class and all other classes are dependent on it revisit your design because it's too tightly coupled.

Comment: I agree about it being easier to use one file instead of multiple small ones but this is for an assignment and they require us to use multiple files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Where do I declare an enum type so that every class header file has access to it?

In its own header. Make a separate header file for your `enum`, and `#include` that header in all other headers that need to use it. Don't forget to add [*include guards*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) to avoid multiple inclusions:

```
#ifndef MOVE_H
#define MOVE_H

enum move foo {
    LEFT, RIGHT, UP, DOWN
};

#endif /* MOVE_H */
```

Note: If you have multiple enumerations that logically belong together, or an `enum` that belongs together with a class, you may want to put the two in the same header.

Comment: I disagree. Have hundreds of small C++ header files is a nightmare.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Did I say anything about hundreds of small headers? Besides, if an `enum` is literally used everywhere as OP suggests, that is logically the way to go.

Comment: No, he could have only one single header file for his entire (presumably small) application! Having one header for each type (i.e. enum or class) is really excessive!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch If the application is small, then it would have few enums. If his enums are logically connected to each other, then it's OK to put them in the same header. If they are not connected to each other, then separate files is the way to go. Besides, modern IDEs have simplified managing multiple headers a lot, so one of the major incentives that was pushing programmers to reduce the number of header files is now gone.

Comment: I ended up putting it in a separate file. The thing that was getting me confused was something my uni tutor pointed out to me; when using #include the linker can only link it once until it has to be re#included if that makes sense.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch What is the downside of having hundreds of small headers? Is it the narrowing down of each one to use when? An IDE should take care of that part for you.